# How to successfully export C++ project template in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I went through the steps to export the Visual C++ Project as a Template in Visual Studio 2015. It only contains one file. Main.cpp

When I open the new project created from that template it gives: "files cannot be found" when I try to click on Main.cpp.

I'm missing something, please help.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information in order to help you. What files are in the exported zip archive? Does it contain the Main.cpp file or is it missing? Also what does the *.vstemplate look like (best paste it's contents here)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how you do it:

1. Goto **File** -> **Export Template ...**
2. Select **Project Template**
3. In the drop down box select the project you want to use as base
4. Click **Next**
5. Enter all information you want/need on the dialog page
6. Make sure **Display an explorer window on the output files folder** is cheked
7. Click **Finish**
8. Open the created zip-archive and add your Main.cpp file to it
9. Extract and open the **MyTemplate.vstemplate** in an text-editor
   The file is an xml-file and the TemplateContent section should look similar to this:

> ```
>   <TemplateContent>
>     <Project TargetFileName="sample.vcxproj" File="sample.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
>       <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">sample.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
>     </Project>
>   </TemplateContent>
> ```

10. Now add an ProjectITem for your Main.cpp file it should look like
     this:

> ```
> <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="Main.cpp">Main.cpp</ProjectItem>
> ```

11. Save the file and replace the one in the zip-archive

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately any answer is just going to be a work around -- this functionality is currently broken in Visual Studio 2015, bug has reported in a couple places:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/732

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2894593/problem-about-export-template-from-c-project